# How to stop a For Loop in a middle and continue from there down back in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a JavaScript code like so:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

for (var i = 0, di = 1; i >= 0; i += di) {    

    if (i == myArray.length - 1)  { di = -1; }

    document.writeln(myArray[i]);
}
```

I need it to stop right in the middle like 10 and from 10 starts counting down to 0 back.

So far, I've managed to make it work from 0 to 20 and from 20 - 0.

How can I stop it in a middle and start it from there back?

Please help anyone!

Comment: So you want to show the first 10 elements in the array then show them in reverse order?

Comment: store the stopped array in new var

Comment: @RaMPrabU could you be a bit more understanding? Maybe post an answer or mark as duplicate?

Comment: @Ryan Wilson correct Ryen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using a function which accepts the array and the number of items you want to display forwards and backwards:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];


if(myArray.length === 1){
   ShowXElementsForwardsAndBackwards(myArray, 1);
}
else if(myArray.length === 0) {
   //Do nothing as there are no elements in array and dividing 0 by 2 would be undefined
}
else {
   ShowXElementsForwardsAndBackwards(myArray, (myArray.length / 2));
}


function ShowXElementsForwardsAndBackwards(mYarray, numberOfItems){
      if (numberOfItems >= mYarray.length) {
             throw "More Numbers requested than length of array!";
      }

      for(let x = 0; x < numberOfItems; x++){
          document.writeln(mYarray[x]);
      }

      for(let y = numberOfItems - 1; y >= 0; y--){
          document.writeln(mYarray[y]);
      }
}
```

Comment: Can't keep the numberOfItems dynamic? since the question asked for the middle of the array, like: `ShowXElementsForwardsAndBackwards(myArray, (myArray.length / 2));`?

Or in the function doesn't keep the numberOfItems parameter and make a var for the middle of the array...

Comment: @CassianoMontanari Added your suggestion to answer

Comment: @CassianoMontanari added if conditions for array length zero and 1

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply! it helps me.

Comment: @Melisa no problem, glad I could help. If you are happy with my answer, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Ryan Wilson just did it =)

Answer (score 1):

Just divide your array length by 2

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

for (var i = 0, di = 1; i >= 0; i += di) {    

    if (i == ((myArray.length / 2) -1 ))  { di = -1; }

    document.writeln(myArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could [Array.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) help you in this matter?

```js
const array = [0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

const getArrayOfAmount = (array, amount) => array.filter((item, index) => index < amount)

let arraySection = getArrayOfAmount(array, 10)

let reversed = [...arraySection].reverse()


console.log(arraySection)
console.log(reversed)
```

And then you can "do stuff" with each array with watever array manipulation you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn’t you just check if you’ve made it halfway and then subtract your current spot from the length?

```
for(i = 0; i <= myArray.length; i++){

   if( Math.round(i/myArray.length) == 1 ){
       document.writeln( myArray[ myArray.length - i] );
    } else {
       document.writeln( myArray[i] );
   }

}
```

Unless I’m missing something?

Comment: I think that the one of the simplest solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you capture the midpoint ( half the length of the array ), just start working your step in the opposite direction.

```js
const N = 20;
let myArray = [...Array(N).keys()];
let midpoint = Math.round(myArray.length/2)

for ( let i=1, step=1; i; i+=step) {

  if (i === midpoint)
    step *= -1
    
  document.writeln(myArray[i])
}
```

To make things clearer, I've:

- Started the loop iterator variable (`i`) at 1; this also meant the array has an unused `0` value at `0` index; in other words, `myArray[0]==0` that's never shown
- Set the the loop terminating condition to `i`, which means when `i==0` the loop will stop because it is *falsy*
- Renamed the `di` to `step`, which is more consistent with other terminology
- The `midpoint` uses a `Math.round()` to ensure it's the highest integer (midpoint) (e.g., `15/2 == 7.5` but you want it to be 8 )
- The `midpoint` is a variable for performance reasons; calculating the midpoint in the loop body is redundant and less efficient since it only needs to be calculated once
- For practical purpose, made sizing the array dynamic using `N`
- Updated to ES6/ES7 -- this is now non-Internet Explorer-friendly [it won't work in IE ;)] primarily due to the use of the spread operator (`...`) ... but that's easily avoidable

Comment: Thank you for your time and the detail explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the checking into the condition block of the for loop.

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

for (
    var i = 0, l = (myArray.length >> 1) - 1, di = 1;
    i === l && (di = -1), i >= 0;
    i += di
) {
    document.writeln(myArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that it is much harder to read, rather than putting it outside and using meaningful variable names

Comment: @BotNet, it is just a proof of concept. in reality, two loops would do best.

Comment: I like this PoC, just better if the variables are described outside the loop definition :)